# Two razor generated form checkboxes returning different values when checked; why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I'm working on modifying Controller logic for two an MVC/Razor generated forms. While debugging my code in order to confirm that my new code is doing what I expected it to do I noticed the following inconsistent behavior.

**Form1** defined in *Form1.cshtml* with `ActionResult1` contains a *checkbox* generated using

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AttributeName, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "onclick", "this.checked=!this.checked;" } })
```

**Form2** defined in *Form2.cshtml* with `ActionResult2` contains a *checkbox* generated using

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AttributeName)
```

They both share the same *Controller* but separate `ActionResult` methods. The troubling behavior is observed when I submit each form:

When **both** checkboxes are ***checked***:

- When I use the debugging console to see the value for the checkbox in **Form1** using `formCollection.GetValue("AttributeName")` I see that it contains the string `"true,false"` therefore returning **`true`** when I perform the following convert

  ```
  Model.AttributeName=(bool)formCollection.GetValue("AttributeName").ConvertTo(typeof(bool))
  ```
- When I use the debugging console to see the value for the checkbox in **Form2** using `formCollection.GetValue("AttributeName")` I see that it contains the string `"false,true"` therefore returning **`false`** when I perform the following convert

  ```
  Model.AttributeName= (bool)formCollection.GetValue("AttributeName").ConvertTo(typeof(bool))`
  ```

Assuming **both** checkboxes are ***NOT checked***:
 - Both forms **Form1** and **Form2** return the string `"false"`

This inconsistent behavior is giving me a hard time because I have both `ActionResult1` and `ActionResult2` use the same following logic after I cast and assign the boolean to `Model.AttributeName`:

```
if (Model.AttributeName){ ModelState.AddModelError("AttributeName", "Checkbox is required."); }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that both forms were not exactly identically coded in terms of their HTML helpers:

**Form1** was declared using strictly HTML helpers inside its enclosing container. Something like this:

```
...
<li  data-role="fieldcontain">
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AttributeName,...
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttributeName, "Checkbox Label String")
<br/>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AttributeName)
</li>
...
```

**Form2** was declared using a mix of HTML ***AND*** helpers inside its enclosing container. Something like this:

```
...
<li  data-role="fieldcontain">
<label>
<span style="float: left;">Checkbox Label String.</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AttributeName)
<br/>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AttributeName)
</label>
</li>
...
```

Apparently it makes a difference, and in fact mixes up the way Razor handles the form if I decide to ***hard-code*** the label rather than using the `@Html.LabelFor(...` helper. Once I replicated **Form1**'s structure in **Form2** they both started returning the same values (`"false"` for not checked, `"true,false"` when checked).

Therefore assigning the right boolean accordignly; `True` for

```
Model.AttributeName=(bool)formCollection.GetValue("AttributeName").ConvertTo(typeof(bool))
```

when checked. `False` when not.